# whenever I write "?" in {{ forms?.title }} the error goes away but the title is not displayed on the page ANGULAR8

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

this is my.component.ts file I had a problem everytime I put "?" in my html file  {{ forms?.contactNumber }} the error goes away but the data isn't displaying. I need to toggle the sidenav for data to be displayed and it's weird

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { DealerapiService } from "../../services/dealerapi.service";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";

@Component({
    selector: "kt-edit-contact",
    templateUrl: "./edit-contact.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./edit-contact.component.scss"]
})
export class EditContactComponent implements OnInit {
    submitted = false;
    forms: Observable<any>;
    profileForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private dealerApiService: DealerapiService,
        private router: Router
    ) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.viewData();
        this.profileForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            contactNumber: ["", Validators.required],
            address: ["", Validators.required]
        });
    }
    viewData() {
        this.dealerApiService.getUser().subscribe(
            (res: any) => {
                this.forms = res.data;
                console.log(res);
            },
            err => {
                console.log(err);
            }
        );
    }

    onSubmit() {
        this.submitted = true;
        if (this.profileForm.invalid) {
            return;
        } else {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "forms" are not an Observable, just an object, so define **forms:any**

Comment: Do you mind sharing your component.html?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

Declare `forms` with a empty object

```
forms: Observable<any> = {}
```

and remove type safe operator `?` from your template

```
 {{ forms.contactNumber }}
```

Comment: Hello the data still isn't displaying but when i click the sidenav it shows up

Comment: but when i'm not adding question mark the data is showing up.

Comment: Im using side nav when i navigate to other page data doesn't appear

Comment: Please create it in  stackbiltz and share

Answer (score 0):

you must assign observable to forms like this

```
  viewData() {
           this.forms= this.dealerApiService.getUser();
        }
```

and in your html use it with async pipe `{{forms | async}}`
and don't forget to unsubscribe it in destroy

https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe

or you can just make it as object not observable `forms: any;`
and in html will be  `{{ forms?.contactNumber }}`

Comment: you don't need to unsubscribe  if you use async pipe 

Comment: Im using side nav when i navigate to other page data doesn't appear

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you forms property is an observale it 's just a object that what I think the dealer api will return so at the time of the component template render the forms is undefined and access to any sub value from undefined object like this forms.contact Number will throw an error like

> Cannot read property 'contactNumber' of undefined

you can solve this problem by one of these solution

1️⃣ initialize the form property with object reference of an empty object

```
forms:any = new User(); // in case you have a class user or just empty object
```

2️⃣ use ngIf to check if the form  has a truthy value

```
<ng-container *ngIf="forms">
  {{form.contactNumber}}
</ng-container>
```

3️⃣ you can use `?.` [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-safe-navigation-operator----and-null-property-paths)

```
 {{form?.contactNumber}}
```

4️⃣ finaly if case you want to use forms as observavle

```
  forms:Observable<any>;


  ngOnInit() {
    this.forms = this.dealerApiService.getUser()
    ...
  }
```

*template*

```html
  <ng-container *ngIf="forms | async as formsData">
   {{formsData.contactNumber}}
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Im using side nav when i navigate to other page data doesn't appear